# Настройка сети для Parallels Desktop с целью динамического анализа вирусов

Tags: сеть, безопасность, вирусы, виртуальная-машина, динамический-анализ

Изучаю книгу

> Practical Malware Analysis(Michael Sikorsky and Andrew Hong)

Для динамического анализа уязвимостей я установила виртуальную машину Parallels с двумя гостевыми ОС (Windows 10 для запуска вируса и Linux для мониторинга сети). Как настроить сеть в Parallels и гостевых ОС так,чтобы вирус не повлиял на работу  основной Mac OS (host).C пониманием этого аспекта большие затруднения.

Comment: Все завист от того какой вирус вы запускаете, но скорее всего для mac проблем не будет. Выже создадите виртуальную сеть. Главное чтобы вы не давли своим виртуальным интерфейсам реальные IP которые используете на Host машине.